# Can't submit upload form in Selenium, Page just refreshes

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to upload an image to instagram's mobile website through selenium. It seems to find the element in question but when I try to submit it, the page merely refreshes.

```
uploadForm=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/nav/div/div/form/input')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.height='auto'; arguments[0].style.visibility='visible';", uploadForm)
#makes form visible
submitForm = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/nav/div/div/form')
#selects whole form
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.height='auto'; arguments[0].style.visibility='visible';", submitForm)
#unhides form as well
uploadForm.send_keys("/testman.JPG")
#sends the file path to the input section of form
submitForm.submit()
#attempts to submit form, causing the refresh
```

Could there be some kind of JS listener preventing me from uploading this way? Here is the code of the form in question[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a .click() on the submit button. Frequently, a dev will put a JavaScript onclick on the button that [prevents the default action](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp). You can see the default action for the form when the page "refreshes". The URL will contain your form as query-string parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, there is no submit button on the form.

Comment: You could try sending the ENTER key to the last form element if that is how you submit manually.

Comment: Hey something interesting happened when I sent (uploadForm.send_keys("/testman.JPG" + Keys.ENTER) I got an error "upload failed only images can be posted"

Comment: I would send enter in a separate command for readability. When doing this manually, how do you submit? We just need to recreate that in code.

Comment: Manually it just opens a Browse window and I select the file and it takes me to the next page

Comment: Selenium handles the browse window by setting the file path as the 
 element's value. There must be some event listener tied to that input. If possible get with your dev and figure out how to trigger that event. You can use the JavaScriptExecutor to do something like dispatching an event. I have had this on a form before where I couldn't submit without triggering the blur() event.

Comment: I have the source for the listener I just can't find out what to trigger

Comment: Any chance you could tell me what to look for?

Comment: It is hard to tell without seeing the page myself. The issue could also stem from you changing the visibility of elements. I wager the user would have to do some other actions to make it visible and recreating that in code is better than modifying the page. There could be listeners to any of those events to show a submit button or auto-submit your form when a certain element gets its value set. The dev who made the page will be your best resource in pinning it down.